# Gameobject not deactivating before timer ends

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

Hello fellow Stack Overflow members, I was using unity and encountered a problem about a gameObject not deactivating while a timer is on. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enable : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
private float Waittime = 49f;
public GameObject Game;


private void Active()
{
    if (Waittime <= 0)
    {
        Game.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log("jlkj");
    }
    else
    {
        Waittime -= Time.deltaTime;
        Game.SetActive(false); 
    }
}
}
```

I have assigned the gameObject in the inspector panel and my code isn't working. Could someone please help me?

Comment: You don't appear to be calling the Active() method.  Should you be calling Active() in the Update() method?

Comment: @HumanWrites how do I mark a comment as the correct answer?

Comment: You can upvote the comment but you can't mark it as correct because it's not an answer.  Bean5 Music has added an answer that you can mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the function Active() called every frame update, if not it will not run the code and not count down the variable Waittime

try using private void Update() if that is the case.